# Unable to get the data from asp:textbox in Jquery popup in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to call this Code behind method through a button which is in Jquery popup. But username and password are ended up being NULL

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strUName= txtNewUname.Text;
    string strUpass = txtNewPassword.Text;
}
```

Here is my Html for the Popup

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <input type="button" id="btnNew" text="NEW" value="ADD" onclick="ShowAddNewPopup()"/>
             <div id="alertPopup" title="Add New User" style="display :none" >
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td class="auto-style2">UserName
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewUname" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td class="auto-style2">Password
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewPassword" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text ="save"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my Script to call the popup:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
     function ShowAddNewPopup() {
         debugger;
         $("#alertPopup").dialog();
     }
    </script> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

this will work out..

```
$("#alertPopup").dialog({
                appendTo: "form"
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm